# How to read whole file but skip commented code in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, c#-4.0

I am creating a windows app that will read all files in directory, here is the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LathropFileScan
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnprint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextWriter text = new StreamWriter("FileScan.csv");
            List<string> files = new List<string>();

            foreach (string folders in Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Users\Desktop\Application","*",SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(folders))
                {
                    int counter = 0;

                    foreach (string innerfile in Directory.GetFiles(folders))
                    {

                            string content = File.ReadAllText(innerfile);

                        if (content.Contains(Path.GetFileName(file)))
                            counter++;

                    }

                    if (counter == 0)
                    {

                            files.Add(file.Substring(34));

                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (string print in files)
            {
                text.Write(print + Environment.NewLine);
            }

            text.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

By using this code I can successfully read all files of the directory but File.ReadAllText() also reads the commented code. I want to skip commented code and just want to read uncommented code. Is there anyway to do that.
Thanks.

Comment: you'd have to use some sort of regex to find comment patterns // and /**/ etc and exclude those

Comment: Which "commented code"? Is this content in the files you are reading? Maybe it's html, maybe it's c# or java, maybe it's BASIC. They all have different notation for comments.

Comment: Sure, just check each line for "//" and ignore if found; and for "/*" and continue ignoring until the closing comment ("*/") is found.

Comment: it's just for .aspx and .aspx.cs pages

Comment: Just? So that's potentially at least four different kinds of comment. `//comment` `/* comment */` `<!-- comment -->` and `<%-- comment --%>`. Of course, whether or not they are treated as comments depends on the context of the comment... is it in a .cs file? Is it in an aspx file? Is it in an html `<script>` tag? Is it contained by a different kind of comment? I could carry on (for a while) thinking of all the problem cases in your "simple" requirement. So, when you say "just want to read uncommented code", I think you are rather underplaying the nature of what you are asking for. Too broad.

Answer (score 3):

If you use ReadAllLines instead of ReadAllText, the bellow code works fine.

```
var newString = "";
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("").ToList();
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    if (line.Contains("//") && line.EndsWith("\n"))
    {
        var startIndex = line.IndexOf("//", StringComparison.Ordinal);
        var endIndex = line.LastIndexOf("\n", StringComparison.Ordinal);
        var length = (endIndex + 1) - startIndex;
        var subString = line.Substring(startIndex, length);
        var temp = line.Replace(subString, "");
        newString += temp;
        //Console.WriteLine(line);
        continue;
    }
    newString += line;
}
//Console.WriteLine(newString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex.Replace method . a sample like this

```
public static string ReadAllLinesWithoutComment()
{
    string path=@"";
    string result = string.Empty;
    string[] tempArry =  File.ReadAllLines(path);

    for (int i = 0; i < tempArry.Length; i++)
        if (tempArry[i].Contains(@"//"))
    tempArry[i] = tempArry[i].Substring(0, tempArry[i].IndexOf(@"//"));

    result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tempArry);

    string pattern = "(/[*]).*[*]/"; // Remove multi line comment (/* */)
    string replacement = "";
    Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Singleline);

    return rgx.Replace(result, replacement);
}
```